# Change symbology of layer from "Single symbol" to "unique value" with python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, symbology

How can I change the symbology of a layer with single symbol to unique values with Python.  I  don't know how to update it.

I used this code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"region")[0]
if lyr.symbologyType == "UNIQUE_SYMBOLE":
  lyr.symbology.valueField = "REGION"
  lyr.symbology.addAllValues()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd
```

---

The code runs but doesn't change anything (no error message) 
the problem is that I want to change the symbology of the layer displaid with single symbol to category "uniques values"?

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include your ArcGIS version and what happens (error message etc) when you run your code, please?

Comment: lyr.symbologyType will never equal "UNIQUE_SYMBOLE".  The list of possible values is: GRADUATED_COLORS, GRADUATED_SYMBOLS, OTHER, UNIQUE_VALUES and RASTER_CLASSIFIED as per the [website on the layer class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/).

Comment: @Fezter I think you should turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Fezter:

> lyr.symbologyType will never equal "UNIQUE_SYMBOLE".  The list of
>   possible values is: GRADUATED_COLORS, GRADUATED_SYMBOLS, OTHER,
>   UNIQUE_VALUES and RASTER_CLASSIFIED as per the [website on the layer
>   class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/).

Answer (score 2):

1. First manually create a layer file with a unique value symbology based on your single symbol layer (not shown below).
2. Then use arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer to update your single symbol layer

   ```
   mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
   df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

   updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "single_symbol_layer", df)[0]
   sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("unique_value_symbol_layer")
   arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df,updateLayer,sourceLayer, symbology_only = True)

   if updateLayer.symbologyType == "UNIQUE_VALUES":
       updateLayer.symbology.valueField = "UniqueValueField"
       updateLayer.symbology.addAllValues()

   arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
   arcpy.RefreshTOC()
   ```

To ensure the values are ordered replace:

```
updateLayer.symbology.valueField = "UniqueValueField"
updateLayer.symbology.addAllValues()
```

with

```
updateLayer.symbology.classValues = listofUniqueValues
updateLayer.symbology.showOtherValues = False
```

You can create the listofUniqueValues by:

```
listofUniqueValues = sorted({row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("single_symbol_layer", ["UniqueValueField"]) if row[0]})
```